# Can't delete in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, html, laravel

I would appreciate if y'all could help me delete in laravel.

My link:

```
<a href="" data-target="#modal-delete-{{$alum->idAlumno}}" data-toggle="modal"><button class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button></a>
...Html tags
@include('sistema.alumno.modal')
```

The code that is supposed to get the job done

```
<div class="modal fade modal-slide-in-right" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="modal-delete-{{$alum->idAlumno}}">
    {{Form::Open(array('action'=>array('AlumnoController@destroy', $alum->idAlumno), 'method' => 'delete'))}}
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Eliminar alumno</h4> //Detele student
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Favor confirme si desea borrar el alumno</p> //Please confirm...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button> //Close
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmar</button> //Confirm
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{Form::Close()}}
</div>
```

The controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $alumno = Alumno::findOrFail($id);
        $alumno->delete();
        return Redirect::to('sistema/alumno');
    }
```

When I click on "Delete", the confirmation pops up. I click confirm, but it doesn't delete; it just takes me to this link: *http://127.0.0.1:8000/sistema/alumno?searchText=&_method=DELETE&_token=yTwg701YRaAxTnYlJueVXxfpNDsvJRLpHGto5bdr*

I tried to type what I think should be the correct link, taking into account the folders sistema(system), alumno(student), one of the ids and the instruction: sistema/alumno/1/delete in vain.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you delete the sublime-text3 tag while editing? It's the exact version of the software I'm using.

Comment: Your question isn't about Sublime, it's about Laravel; the text editor you use to write your code doesn't have any bearing on why the code you wrote with it doesn't work.

Comment: I get that. On the other hand, it's kind of disappointing not to get a satisfying answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use method post in form tag following code :

```
div class="modal fade modal-slide-in-right" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="modal-delete-{{$alum->idAlumno}}">
    {{Form::Open(array('action'=>array('AlumnoController@destroy', $alum->idAlumno), 'method' => 'post'))}}
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Eliminar alumno</h4> //Detele student
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Favor confirme si desea borrar el alumno</p> //Please confirm...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button> //Close
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmar</button> //Confirm
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{Form::Close()}}
</div>
```

The controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $delete = Alumno::destroy($id);
        return Redirect::to('sistema/alumno');
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say this: it didn't work. I also checked in the database.

Comment: No error, it's as if I hadn't made any changes. I mean, it does what it did before: nothing.

Comment: can you give me your server details so i can check it ?

Comment: Where can I find them? I'm sorry, I'm new to web design.

Comment: You can share your cpanel details with me and site url

Comment: I would, if the website were hosted somewhere. For now, it is on localhost.

Comment: Ok, can you give me teamviewer access

Comment: Sorry, can't. Thanks for the help, though.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP DELETE directive is not supported by any server, and so Laravel "hides it" in a hidden input, so you have to use `method => post` and add the method `DELETE` as input (you can use Blade tag `@method`):

```
{{Form::Open(array('action'=>array('AlumnoController@destroy', $alum->idAlumno), 'method' => 'post'))}}
@method('delete')
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Eliminar alumno</h4> //Detele student
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Favor confirme si desea borrar el alumno</p> //Please confirm...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button> //Close
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Confirmar</button> //Confirm
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{{Form::Close()}}
```

Comment: When I copy your answer exactly like you wrote it, it just leaves me with lots of confirmation dialogs embedded in the website, along with "@method('delete')" lines . If I add the line I had at the top, it's pretty much what I had before.

Comment: please check in the console what the server respond  to the request when you click the button... also this in just the form, in the your example there is other likes of code: do not remove those, they doesn't matter just for the snipped, but maybe in the JS logic yes

Comment: Do you mean cmd? If so, it just loads some css and js files

Comment: i mean the "<div class="modal fade..." div wrapper around the form, i've just not copied it, but you have to leave it on your page

Comment: I kept the div wrapper. I also didn't delete code from other "likes of code". The console (cmd) is displaying the usual stuff.

Comment: so you have the modal-fade ecc ecc and the code you have inside you have copied by this answer, but when you confirm the deletion with the button, what happens?

Comment: Yes, I do have all of that. It behaves as if I had clicked "refresh".

Comment: check if it deletes the data